# When using mix-blend-mode: difference; is it possible to add greyscale/monotone via CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css

When using mix-blend-mode: difference; is it possible to add greyscale/monotone via CSS or JS?

[Here's a pen of our current solution](https://codepen.io/flamering/pen/BaGVMBG). (Press 'g' to activate the greyscale).

Works great, ***except*** on Safari where it breaks and displays the text as black.

Any ideas on an alternate solution to this which has browser support?

Thanks!

```js
let grayscale = true
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (e.metaKey) return;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 71: // G
            if (grayscale) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.color').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('toggle'))
            } else {
                document.querySelectorAll('.color').forEach(el => el.classList.add('toggle'))
            }
            grayscale = !grayscale
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smooth: always;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63,94,251,1) 0%, rgba(66,165,207,1) 17%, rgba(203,136,66,1) 48%, rgba(187,76,85,1) 72%, rgba(70,252,154,1) 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.fixed {
  font-size: 5rem;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.absolute {
  font-size: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.difference {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.color {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  z-index: 1;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container relative">
  <span class="difference fixed">Fixed – </span>
  <span class="color fixed toggle">Fixed – </span>
  <span class="difference absolute">Absolute – </span>
  <span class="color absolute toggle">Absolute – </span>
</div>
```